# Setting Disabled to True for a group of employees

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query who gets me the Employee who are disabled where I am using DISTINCT because the table is containing the history of modification for each employee :

```
SELECT e.EmployeeId,e.Disabled FROM Staging.dbo.Employee e
WHERE e.Disabled=1
```

Output :

```
EmployeeId Disabled
50         1
50         1
45         1
445        1
```

I am trying to update my second table like below based on the staging knowing that it is an improved version of the staging one :

```
UPDATE [DimEmployee] 
SET Disabled=1
WHERE  exists (SELECT DISTINCT e.EmployeeId,e.Disabled FROM DW_Staging.dbo.Employee e
WHERE e.Disabled=1 )
```

Once I execute the query, it is setting Disabled=1 for all the records. Current Output for DimEmployee :

```
EmployeeId Disabled
50         NULL
50         NULL
45         NULL
445        NULL
```

After the update :

```
EmployeeId Disabled
    50         1
    50         1
    45         1
    445        1
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Your statement about the use of `select distinct` is just misleading and seems wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use correlation :

```
UPDATE DE
     SET DE.Disabled = 1
FROM [DimEmployee] DE
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM DW_Staging.dbo.Employee e
              WHERE e.Disabled = 1  AND
                    e.EmployeeId = DE.EmployeeId -- Correlation 
             );
```

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, you want the most recent record from staging for each employee.  That suggests:

```
UPDATE e
    SET Disabled = se.Disabled
    FROM DimEmployee e JOIN
         (SELECT se.*,
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY se.EmployeeId
                                    ORDER BY se.modificationDate DESC  -- or whatever the appropriate column is
                                   ) as seqnum
          FROM DW_Staging.dbo.Employee se
         ) se
         ON se.employeeId = e.employeeId AND se.seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the column `Disabled`'s data type is `bit` or `int` with values `0` or `1`, so you can use a correlated subquery in the WHERE clause like this:

```
UPDATE d
SET d.Disabled = 1
FROM [DimEmployee] d
WHERE (SELECT MAX(Disabled) FROM DW_Staging.dbo.Employee WHERE EmployeeID = d.EmployeeID) = 1
```